# QgsTask never executed

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I would like to run a QgsTask when I push a button in a Qgis plugin (3.10).
My task is a subclass similar to [this example](https://www.opengis.ch/fr/2018/06/22/threads-in-pyqgis3/)

In the main class of my plugin, I have added this (connected to the button that works) :

```
def myBtnAction(self) :
    from .my_task import MyTask
    task = MyTask('run my task', 20)
    QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(task)
```

The task is never executed.

Comment: Which qgis 3.10 version are you running? Is it up to date?

Comment: I use the last version of QGIS LTR, up to date.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not executed? Or is its finished method never called maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the standalone version running in PyQGIS Python console like below (clearly borrowed from your link and reindented)?

```py
class MyTask(QgsTask):
    def __init__(self, description, flags):
        super().__init__(description, flags)
    def run(self):
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Started task {}'.format(self.description()))
        #print('crashandburn')
        return True

t1 = MyTask('waste cpu', QgsTask.CanCancel)
QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(t1)
```

In my case, it "works". So what does `MyTask` from your `from .my_task import MyTask` looks like? Did you try to use your task code outside the plugin to find where the issue could be?

Comment: Yes, the code works well in the python console, no problem.
Nothing blocking i've tested on a new plugin from scratch to be sure that the problem doesn't come from my code.